# how to print lists separately instead of merging them?

Tags: python, list, loops

The `data`, `dic` and `abst` are the lists, data in the form of: `[[0, 1, 0, 0 , 1...0],[1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1....0]]`, after the loop, I got the results like this:

`abst = ['PS50802', 'PS50803', 'PS50804', 'PS50805', 'PS50806', 'PS50807', 'PS50808', 'PS50809', 'PS50810', 'PS50811', 'PS50812', 'PS50813', 'PS50814',......]`

`dic = ['PS50102' 'PS50101' 'PS50106' 'PS50199' 'PS50196' 'PS00832' 'PS50072'...]`

> [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0,
>   0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0]

Looks like the two individual lists merged into one list, but how can I get the results like this:

> [[0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0,
>   0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0]]

```
lines = []

for x in range(0, 2):
    for item in dic:
        for i,j in enumerate(abst):       
            if item == j:
                lines.append(data[x][i])

print lines
```

Comment: Can you fix your second result? It is missing a bracket

Comment: Can you post a simplified version of your data,dic and abst variables and precise what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: @HarryPotfleur, yes, I did.

Comment: what does the abst and dic do? Are you going to do a check if both items exist in list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to keep a list of two lists, you can try this:

```
lines = []
for x in range(0, 2):
    line = []
    for item in dic:
        for i,j in enumerate(abst):       
            if item == j:
                line.append(data[x][i])
    lines.append(line)

print lines
```

which you might be able to simplify

```
lines = []
for x in range(0, 2):
    line = []
    for item in dic:
        if item in abst:
            i = abst.index(item)
            line.append(data[x][i])
    lines.append(line)
```

or

```
lines = []
for x in range(0, 2):
    line = [data[x][abst.index(item)] for item in dic if item in abst]
    lines.append(line)
```

Finally, with one list comprehension:

```
lines = [ [data[x][abst.index(item)] for item in dic if item in abst] for x in range(0, 2) ]
```